# Can't get authentication code

Tags: android, delphi, authentication, oauth, google-api

I want to work with Google Api using Rest (Delphi XE7), do it this way:

```
uses
 ...
 {$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
    REST.Authenticator.OAuth.WebForm.FMX;
 {$ENDIF}
 {$IF DEFINED(MsWindows)}
    REST.Authenticator.OAuth.WebForm.Win;
 {$ENDIF}
```

That procedure is working on Windows, after that programm changes AuchCode to access token and everything working.

```
procedure TForm2.OAuth2_GoogleTasks_BrowserTitleChanged(const ATitle:  string;  var DoCloseWebView: boolean);
begin
  if Pos('Success code', ATitle) > 0 then
  begin
    AuthCode := Copy(ATitle, 14, Length(ATitle));
    if (AuthCode <> '') then
    begin
      editactoken.Text:= AuthCode;
      DoCloseWebView := true;
     webform.Release;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button59Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    WebForm:=Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(nil);
    WebForm.OnTitleChanged  := self.OAuth2_GoogleTasks_BrowserTitleChanged;    
    WebForm.ShowWithURL(OAuth2Authenticator1.AuthorizationRequestURI);
end;
```

But I've met a trouble that I cant copy auth code on android:

[image]

1. Form2.OAuth2_GoogleTasks_BrowserTitleChanged doesn't work because title doesn't change;
2. There is no title at all in REST.Authenticator.OAuth.WebForm.FMX :

   ```
           private
   { Private declarations }
   FOnBeforeRedirect: TOAuth2WebFormRedirectEvent;
   FOnAfterRedirect: TOAuth2WebFormRedirectEvent;
   FOnBrowserTitleChanged : TOAuth2WebFormTitleChangedEvent;


   FLastURL: string;
   public
   ```

while in REST.Authenticator.OAuth.WebForm.Win it looks like this:

```
            private
     { Private declarations }
    FOnBeforeRedirect: TOAuth2WebFormRedirectEvent;
    FOnAfterRedirect: TOAuth2WebFormRedirectEvent;
    FOnBrowserTitleChanged : TOAuth2WebFormTitleChangedEvent;


    FLastTitle: string;  // <------- 
    FLastURL: string
```

3. there is no property webform.lasttitle in fmx variant (in win i could get it)
4. LastUrl property looks like that after redirecting : "......" but I can't understand how to use it to get auth code.
5. Try to use IFMXClipboardService but could not get this text from Twebbrowser.
6. Google not allowed to use Http get method for lastUrl adress to get response and parse this code (error 405).
7. I've read some article that there is no way to get html code from webbrowser fmx, is it so?

Any ideas how can I get this code in my programm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android (with Google Play Services installed) provides a native solution for authentication with other Google APIs, where no web browser is required:

See https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth:

> When you want your Android app to access Google APIs using the user's
>   Google account over HTTP, the [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) class and related APIs
>   provide your users a secure and consistent experience for picking an
>   account and retrieving an OAuth 2.0 token for your app.
>
> You can then use that token in your HTTP-based communications with
>   Google API services that are not included in the Google Play services
>   library, such as the Blogger or Translate APIs.

I suggest to do some research in this direction. The page linked above also mentions the [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) for some (non HTTP) services.

Comment: well, it's a bit harder for me to understand how to convert code from links above from java to delphi. There are no samples. 
Also I use this mechanism to get access to google drive from desktop app, but anyway, thank you for clarification.